# Перемещение камеры в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мы ставим палец\мышь в точку на экране и изменяем положение мыши\пальца- камера перемещается. Проблема в том, что перемещение идет не пропорционально. Точка суши должна оставаться под пальцем при перемещении, а не уплывать. Камера на данный момент может иметь разную Y координату, по этому просто подогнать настройки скорости перемещения- не вариант.
Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 1):

хехех... 
    юзай

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z+distance));
```

Comment: уж лучше Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0,0,distance));